# How many clients can a MQTT broker handle?

Tags: mqtt

MQTT is a publish/subscribe protocol. Whenever a publisher publishes to a topic, all the subscribers that have subscribed to that topic will get the message via an MQTT broker. I would like to know the maximum number of clients an MQTT broker can handle. Is there any upper limit for that?

Comment: No, no upper limit. Some MQTT brokers support more than 10.000.000 connections for a MQTT broker cluster which can be seen in this benchmark: https://www.hivemq.com/benchmark-10-million

Answer (score 6):

HiveMQ [has a whitepaper](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/hyperscale-iot-iiot-applications-up-to-200-mil-connections-with-hivemq/) that shows a benchmark of 200 million clients.

They showed 40 million publishers and 160 million consumers IIRC.

This is done with their broker clustering tech which is a feature their premium product has.

Answer (score 4):

How many clients an MQTT broker can serve depends on the MQTT broker software you're using. Most MQTT brokers will likely only be limited by the amount of memory available (each socket uses a chunk of memory) and it therefore becomes a question of which broker software utilizes the memory (and other resources) in the most efficient manner. Of course some brokers might have other limitations.

In practice you'd also have to look at what you can do with the connected clients - some brokers may behave differently (performance wise) depending on how many clients are connected etc.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to work this out is to test depending on your specific workload.

It will be entirely dependent on the following:

1. The size of the machine you run the broker on.
2. The size of the messages you send.
3. The rate of messages.
4. The number of clients (both subscribers and publishers).
5. The performance characteristics you need to meet.
6. Which broker you are using.

And possibly many more factors.

Comment: Network characteristics (gateways. response time) between clients and broker, QOS, connect/disconnect rate, SSL vs. no SSL, etc