# How many simultaneous clients does it support vernemq or mosquitto on server?

Tags: mosquitto, debian-stretch, mqtt-vernemq

I want to buy a vps with the following specifications:

- 2 Core (s) 2.4 GHz
- 8 GB of RAM
- Debian 9 x64

and a dedicated server

- CPU: Intel Xeon E3-1245v5 - 4 / 8t - 3.5GHz /3.9GHz
- RAM: 16GB DDR4 ECC 2133 MHz
- Disks: SoftRaid 2x2TB
- Debian 9 x64

How many connected clients does each server support with vernemq or mosquitto with QOS 1?

Comment: if it's a web services question. I have an android app that through mqtt I use to collect data in real time for farms. Maybe you can help me as I wait for around 2000 clients and I need to cover those clients

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many clients can a MQTT broker handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148237/how-many-clients-can-a-mqtt-broker-handle)

Comment: There are too many variables to answer this sort of question, the only way to find out is to test

Comment: hi, how can i do those tests simulating that amount of devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have solved the doubt, for more than 1000 users you just have to modify the file /etc/init.d/mosquitto

add the following line to the beginning of the file

```
ulimit -n 20000
```

where 20000 is the number of connections to support